# Sombrero bacon - Winter Bash

Tags: soporte, winterbash-2016

Sé que el tema de los sombreros no es demasiado relevante al sitio en cuanto a que no afecta para nada al funcionamiento normal del sitio (excepto que salimos más monos :P).

Sin embargo, ha habido algo que me ha llamado la atención. Esta es la descripción del sombrero bacon:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta donde yo sé (a no ser de que me haya saltado un día durmiendo), hoy es 29 de Diciembre y como se puede observar el sombrero especifica que se consigue el 30 de Diciembre.

Como podéis observar también, sí, he conseguido el sombrero hoy.

¿Qué hora toma como referencia el sistema? ¿He entrado en alguna especie de universo paralelo?

Comment: Eres un viajero del tiempo y vienes del futuro a relucir tu sombrero :O!

Comment: Para todos estos sombreros las fechas son relativas. Considera "30 de diciembre" como "momento temporal en el que en algún lugar del mundo es 30 de diciembre". Por lo tanto, es desde el 29 de diciembre 12am UTC a 31 de diciembre 12am UTC".

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, eso es lo que me imaginaba, que en alguna parte del mundo ya sería 30 de diciembre y estaría tomando como referencia ese valor. Muchas gracias por la aclaración sin embargo.

Comment: Lo que me gustaría es encontrar alguna referencia oficial. Recuerdo haberlo leído en [meta.se].

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, aparte de las bromas de la pregunta, yo quería saber a ver si alguien tenía una referencia oficial sobre cómo son contados los días en los sombreros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta está en *[Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/304899)*:

> A menos que los requerimientos mencionen los husos horarios, los
>   sombreros que dependen de una fecha se ganan generalmente entre 14
>   horas antes y 12 horas después de la fecha especificada en UTC, de
>   modo de podernos adaptar a las personas que están en los diferentes
>   lugares del mundo. Esto implica que puedes ganar ese sombrero, incluso
>   cuando ni siquiera es ese día en donde estás.

El sombrero Mmmm Bacon se puede obtener entre las 00:00 UTC+14 y las 23:59 UTC-12 del 29/12.

O, visto desde el huso en el que estás (GMT+1), desde las 11:00 a.m. del día anterior hasta la 12:59 p.m. del día posterior.